# Is there a name for the hypergeometric function with more parameters than Lauricella but more variables than Kampé de Fériet?

Tags: reference-request, special-functions, hypergeometric-functions

Some background:

The [Appell functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Appell_series) generalise the hypergeometric function ${}_2F_1$ to two variables.

The [Lauricella functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lauricella_hypergeometric_series) generalise this to even more variables.

The [Kampé de Fériet function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kamp%C3%A9_de_F%C3%A9riet_function) generalises the Appell function in a different direction. It has two variables but four arbitrary sets of parameters. It's similar to the way that ${}_pF_q$ is a generalisation of ${}_2F_1$.

It seems natural to extend this to a function that generalises Appell in both directions, with any number of variables and parameters. I'm aware of some even more general functions such as the Srivastava-Daoust function, which has lots of extra $\theta$ and $\phi$ parameters that I don't need. I'm hoping there's a name for something in between.

Basically I'm looking for a name for this function:
$${}^{p+q}F^{(t)}_{r+s} \left(
\begin{matrix}
a_1,\cdots,a_p\colon 
\begin{pmatrix} 
b_{11} & \cdots & b_{1q}\\
\vdots && \vdots \\
b_{t1} &\cdots & b_{tq} \end{pmatrix}
 ; \\
c_1,\cdots,c_r\colon 
\begin{pmatrix} 
d_{11} & \cdots & d_{1s}\\
\vdots && \vdots \\
d_{t1} &\cdots & d_{ts} \end{pmatrix};
\end{matrix}
x_1, \cdots, x_t \right)=\\
\sum_{n_1=0}^\infty \cdots \sum_{n_t=0}^\infty\frac{(a_1)_{\sum_j n_j}\cdots(a_p)_{\sum_j n_j}}{(c_1)_{\sum_j n_j}\cdots(c_r)_{\sum_j n_j}}\frac{\prod_{i=1}^t \prod_{j=1}^q (b_{ij})_{n_i}}{\prod_{i=1}^t \prod_{j=1}^s (d_{ij})_{n_i}}\cdot \frac{x_1^{n_1} \cdots x_t^{n_t}}{n_1! \cdots n_t!}.$$

Comment: Try searching a multivariable Kampé de Fériet function, but I am not sure if will be an “official” function.

Comment: [This post](https://mathoverflow.net/q/450112/12905) uses the Gauss hypergeometric function, one Appell series, and one Lauricella function to solve the reduced sextic, septic, and octic, respectively.