# Hilbert's 13th Problem and series solutions for the reduced sextic, septic, and octic?

Tags: polynomials, sequences-and-series, special-functions, hypergeometric-functions

**I. Reduced equations**

One can eliminate 3 terms from the general *quintic*, *sextic*, *septic*, and *octic* using a Bring-Jerrard transformation to get the reduced forms in radicals,

$$x^5+(x+p) = 0$$
$$x^6+(x+p)(x+q) = 0$$
$$x^7+(x+p)(x+q)(x+r) = 0$$
$$x^8+(x+p)(x+q)(x+r)(x+s) = 0$$

*Note*: It is assumed the constant term $pqrs \neq 0$. Incidentally, Hilbert, using a geometric approach involving 27 lines, managed to eliminate **four** terms from the general nonic reducing it to,

$$x^9+(x+p)(x+q)(x+r)(x+s) = 0$$

though it seems one may have to solve a deg-5 or deg-6, hence may not be in radicals. (See Section 4 of [Sutherland's 2021 paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/2106.09247).)

---

**II. Solutions to the above**

The series solution to the reduced degree $m=5$ is well-known,

$$x = -\sum_{k=0}^\infty(-1)^k\frac{(5k)!}{k!(4k+1)!}\;p^{4k+1}$$

which can be extended via analytic continuation using the *generalized hypergeometric function* ${_4F_3}.$ In these posts [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4728274/4781) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4728991/4781), user Tyma Gaidash also found series solutions to the reduced sextic, septic, and octic given above as,

$$x_k=\sum_{n=1}^\infty e^\frac{(2k+1)\pi i n}6 \frac{q^\frac n6\left(\frac n6\right)!}{p^{\frac{5n}6-1}\big(1-\frac{5n}6\big)!\,n!}\,{_2 F_1}\left(1-n,-\frac n6;2-\frac{5n}6;\color{blue}{\frac pq}\right)$$

$$x_k =\sum_{n=1}^\infty e^\frac{(2k+1)\pi i n}7 \frac{(qr)^\frac n7\left(\frac n7\right)!}{p^{\frac{6n}7-1}\big(1-\frac{6n}7\big)!\,n!}\, \operatorname{F}_1\left(1-n;-\frac n7,-\frac n7;2-\frac{6n}7;\color{blue}{\frac pq,\frac pr}\right)$$

$$x_k=\sum_{n=1}^\infty e^\frac{(2k+1)\pi i n}8\frac{(qrs)^\frac n8\left(\frac n8\right)!}{p^{\frac{7n}8-1}\left(1-\frac{7n}8\right)!\,n!}\, F_D^{(3)}\left(1-n;-\frac n8,-\frac n8,-\frac n8;2-\frac{7n}8;\color{blue}{\frac pq,\frac pr,\frac ps}\right)$$

for all roots $x_k$ with $k = 0,1,\dots m-1,$ using the *hypergeometric function* ${_2F_1},$ *[Appell function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Appell_series)* $\text{F}_1,$ and *[Lauricella function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lauricella_hypergeometric_series)* $F_D^{(3)}$, respectively.

---

**III. Hilbert's 13th**

[Hilbert's 13th Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%27s_thirteenth_problem) asked if the reduced septic's roots, considered as a function of the **three** variables $(p,q,r)$, can be expressed as the composition of a *finite* number of **two**-variable functions. Tyma's solution for the septic does use the **two**-variable Appell function $\text{F}_1,$ though one must sum an infinite number of them.

---

**IV. Questions**

1. Why does Hilbert start with the septic? Is it known that the reduced sextic's roots, as a function of the **two** parameters $(p,q)$ can be expressed as a composition of a finite number of **one**-variable functions?
2. And via analytic continuation, are Tyma's series the *complete* solution for the reduced sextic, septic, and octic for arbitrary $(p,q,r,s)$ as long as its constant term $pqrs \neq 0$?

Comment: The series do not converge seemingly if one of the  parameters has absolute value less than one.

Comment: @TymaGaidash It says [in this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Appell_series) that Appell $F_1(a,b_1,b_2;c;\beta_1,\beta_2)$ is defined for $|\beta_1|<1,\,|\beta_2|<1$, but, for **other** $(\beta_1,\beta_2)$, can be extended by analytic continuation and gave another formula. So there should be a way to make it converge.

Comment: Related [MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/23094/12905).

Comment: Possibly related: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/422922/can-a-general-quintic-be-solved-using-inverse-beta-regularized-function

Comment: Can you please explain how the infinite-series solutions are related to the Hilbert problem which is about closed-form solutions?

Comment: @Anixx More precisely, Hilbert's 13th asks if the reduced septic $x^7+ax^3+bx^2+cx+1$ with _three_ parameters can be solved using a finite composition of a function of _two_ variables. It is well-known that the reduced sextic can solved by the two-variable Kampe de Feriet function. So it seems surprising that the septic can be solved by a two-variable function (the Appell F1) as well. The non-radical solution to the Bring quintic is a series solution called the Bring radical. Therefore, series solutions are not automatically excluded in the toolkit of solving equations, you know.

Comment: Each term in the septic expansion above is a function of 3variables, p, q and r (not counting the root index k).

Comment: @Anixx: Oh, you mean,the factors $(p,q,r)$ _outside_ the Appell function? I believe we just express it as powers of reciprocals of $\beta_1 = \frac{p}{q}, \beta_2 = \frac{p}{r}$, hence $\frac{q}{p}$ and $\frac{r}{p}$.

Comment: @TitoPiezasIII The coefficients in each term outside the $F$ functions also have p's and q's.

Comment: @Anixx Yes, there may be transformations to have the $F$ functions absorb those factors. I will notify Tyma if he has suggestions.